# Resolving an NSManagedObject conflict with multiple threads, relationships, and pointers

Tags: core-data, conflict, nsmanagedobject

I'm having a conflict when saving a bunch of NSManagedObjects via an outside thread.  For starters, I can tell you the following:

1. I'm using a separate MOC for each thread.
2. The MOCs share the same persistent store coordinator.
3. It's likely that an outside thread is modifying one or many of the records that I'm saving.

OK, so with that out of the way, here's what I'm doing.

In my outside thread, I'm doing some computation and updating a single value in a bunch of managed objects.  I do this by looking up the object in the persistent store by my primary key, modifying the single decimal property, and then calling save on the bunch all at once.

In the meantime, I believe the main thread is doing some updating of its own.

When my outside thread does its big save on its managed object context, I get an exception thrown stating a large number of conflicts.  All of the conflicts seem to be centered around a single relationship on each record.  Though the managed object in the persistent store and my outside thread share the same ObjectID for this relationship, they don't share the same pointer.  Based on what I see, that's the only thing that's different between the objects in my NSMergeConflict debug output.

It makes sense to me why the two objects have relationships with different pointers -- they're in different threads.  However, as I understand it from Apple's documentation, the only thing cached when an object is first retrieved from the persistent store are the global IDs.  So, one would think that when I run save on the outside thread MOC, it compares the ObjectIDs, sees they're the same, and lets it all through.

So, can anyone tell me why I'm getting a conflict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems as though this bug was actually being caused by something else -- I was calling the operation causing the error more than once at the same time when I shouldn't have been. Although this doesn't answer the initial question as to why pointers matter in conflicts, updating my code to prevent this situation has resolved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

Per the documentation in the *Concurrency with Core Data* chapter of **The Core Data Programming Guide**, the recommended configuration is for the contexts to share the same persistent store coordinator, not just the same persistent store.

Also, the section *Track Changes in Other Threads Using Notifications* of the same chapter states if you're tracking updates with the **NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification** then you send **-mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification** to the main thread's context so it can merge the changes. But if you're tracking with **NSManagedObjectContextDidChangeNotification** then the external thread should send the object IDs of the modified objects to the main thread which will then send **-refreshObject:mergeChanges:** to its context for each modified object.

And really, you should know if the main thread is also performing updates through its controller, and propagate its changes in like manner but in the opposite direction.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'll look into how I'm using the persistent store coordinator - I haven't looked at that yet.  As for the notifications, I'm using NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification to listen on the main thread for updates and am merging them in.  Unfortunately, it's the external thread that's throwing the error and although I could add merges in that direction, I'm wondering specifically why there's a conflict when no fields seem to be updated except for the pointer (not the ObjectID) of a relationship.

Comment: I just checked - I'm not only using the same persistent store, but the same persistent store coordinator as well, so there should be no problem there.

Comment: Indeed. How are you updating the objects in the main thread's context?

Comment: Just like you said, I'm using NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification and am using mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification.  The error gets triggered from the external thread, though, meaning it's more likely that changes from the main thread aren't getting updated in the external thread.  However, that still begs the question, why is the conflict happening if there aren't any conflicting fields other than a relationship with a different pointer?

Comment: You might need to refresh the objects in the external thread before changing and saving them. Make that a critical section with a lock to ensure the main thread doesn't alter them as the changes are occurring.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, as you can see from my comment above, the issue was related to something else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have all your contexts listening for NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification from any context that makes changes. Otherwise, only the front context will be aware of changes made on the background threads but the background context won't be aware of changes on the front thread.

So, if you have three threads and three context each of which makes changes, all three context must register for notifications from the other two.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I knew this might help solve the conflict from happening, however, my main question was why the 2 were conflicting in the first place.  Unfortunately, as you can see in my comment above, we may never know the true answer.  Thank you anyway!